# Using CASE statement along with SELECT in SQLite to exclude displaying certain results

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, group-by, case

I was trying to solve the problem of "The number of people of each gender there are in the database, where the gender is known, display the count of people against each gender" in SQLite. I typed a query

`SELECT sex, COUNT(name) from employee_table GROUP BY sex ORDER BY sex DESC;`

which is partially correct as it showed as output the number of males and females. But, it also shows the number of blank entries which were neither classified as Male or Female.

I have to stop displaying the count of the blank entries. I guess for this, I have to use a CASE statement. I tried CASE statement in different ways. But those didn't work. I tried searching the internet and stack overflow and tried those methods. Those also didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Richard

Comment: *I tried searching the internet and stack overflow and tried those methods.* and you didn't see the use of the WHERE clause?

Comment: That is an interesting point. It is actually worse. I am not sure about finding WHERE clause by the last internet search; but I used it several times to solve several problems without checking internet. Even recently like yesterday or day before yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to *filter* the results and a `case` expression doesn't do that.  Without sample data, it is difficult to say *exactly* what the expression is, but perhaps:

```
SELECT sex, COUNT(name) 
FROM employee_table
WHERE sex IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY sex
ORDER BY sex DESC;
```

If the "blank" results are really empty strings, then that would be:

```
WHERE sex <> ''
```

This also filters out `NULL` values.

Or if you want explicit values, then you can use `IN`:

```
WHERE sex IN ('m', 'f')
```

Comment: Even though your second choice provided correct output for me, I found a better answer myself: by using WHERE sex =='m' or sex =='f'. I did not answer my question myself; because your answer sparked mine. Thanks anyway.